# Windows 10 taskbar on top - clipping all open programs

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

I like having my Windows 10 taskbar located on the top of my display; however, on my recent build with a new monitor (I'm not sure if curved monitors have a different aspect ratio or something causing this issue), I notice that my taskbar will always overlap open windows, such as Chrome, to some degree, as shown:

[image: overlapping taskbar]

I have tried unlocking/relocking and various other 'turn off then on' methods to no avail; any tips as to why this could be occuring? Running at 1080p with 100% scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions are offered by a [Microsoft forum poster](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/b558e0ad-e741-49b5-9cf0-2769611be16c), one of which required correction (provided):

A. Taskbar oversized?

A1. Right-click in the taskbar in a black space. If the taskbar is locked, iyou will see a check mark by it; clicking on Lock the taskbar, to clear that check mark and remove the lock.

A2. Move the cursor over to the taskbar's edge until the pointer morphs into a double-headed arrow‍‍. That shows the taskbar can be resized. Now, drag the border to resize tit.

B. Corrupted Windows?

B1. Click on the windows START icon at upper left, scroll down, and choose Windows System

B2. Right click on Command Prompt, choose More and Run as Administrator

B3. Run `sfc /scannow`

B4. Reboot then recheck the taskbar's overlap.

B5. If not resolved, repeat B1-B2, then do

`DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth`

`DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`

Restart the computer after those complete

Comment: It appears that you copied parts of answer from https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop-winpc/windows-10-taskbar-covers-and-overlaps-windows/f1b84d60-aaa5-4475-acfb-d75b949107ba. You're using someone's work without giving the author credit. This amounts to plagiarism, and is not welcome on [SU]. Remember to always add prominent attribution and appropriate block quoting when using other sources. Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing).

Comment: And, corrected things which did not work.

Comment: @K7AAY - It was similar enough, to the author's original words, I recognized the writing style of who actually originally wrote those suggestions.  *In other words, what you wrote, clearly were not your own original words.*